# Wordpress Error ! failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, file, permissions

I get this error when I open the home page of my website
I don't know whats wrong can anyone help me out.

I think the issue is related to some file permissions.

EDIT 1: I changed the file permissions and now the site works but the problem is that the images are not getting displayed. So when logged in to the WordPress admin dashboard. I found few error messages. Check the screenshot.
[image]

Comment: Are you on a linux environment? change your the owner/group for your file as defined on your web server's configuration using **chown**. Change permissions to 640 to that file using **chmod**. 640 means 6 - owner has read and write permissions, and 4 - group has read permissions, 0 - everyone else should be denied access. read more by consulting the [man](http://www.linfo.org/man.html) pages

Comment: Two things. First, check if the components.json exists in a correct directory you point out. Second, check the owner of the file. Well, you have to change the mode of file to 666 if possible.

Comment: Hey @tommybee thank, I have changed the components.json file permissions and the site is working.
But I have encountered another problem that none of my images are visible. So on further examination when I logged in into the WordPress admin dashboard I see this error messages:

** File Permission Issues
We were unable to modify required files. Please ensure that /home/adarshmotors/public_html/wp-content/uploads/ has the proper read-write permissions, or modify your wp-config.php file to contain your FTP login credentials as outlined here..**

Comment: Well, I think that the owner of the json file is different with your running environment. You should test the directory with 777 or 666 first. chmod -R option. /home/adarshmotors/public_html/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be also a permission problem:

- All directories should be 755 or 750.
- All files should be 644 or 640.

try this, or visit [URL 1](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30355/failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied-while-writing-to-an-xml-file-in-a-wordp), [URL 2](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213916825-WordPress-sites-are-not-accessible-failed-to-open-stream-Permission-denied)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi, Im using cPanel and its difficult ti update each and every folder and file.

Comment: you can use "Recurse into subdirectories" option for it, it will apply for current folder and it's subfolders. check, [here](http://www.georgekatsoudas.com/contact/knowledgebase.php?article=78)

Comment: also wp-content should be owned by the apache user e.g. www-data and for security reasons the other foldres should not be owned by www-data

Answer (score 2):

Above answers are right , it looks like permission error.

For running WordPress correctly permission should be as below

All directories should be 755
All files should be 644

You also need to check ownership and group as well.

Ownership of file may depends on which server you are using , for example ubantu should have owner/group = apache/apache

You can easily change permission by using below command .

sudo chown -R username:group directory

will change ownership (both user and group) of all files and directories inside of directory and directory itself.

Comment: Hey thanks for helping. But now I have found another problem. Check the EDIT 1 section in the question.

Comment: Thanks man, your answer help me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

For this issue, you can re-installed the Visual Composer plugin. and after activate the plugin from backend. check it.

I hope that you can get the solution after using this step.

Share the post comment for the same bug: https://edge.ticksy.com/ticket/1235319/

Comment: Hey thanks for helping. But now I have found another problem. Check the EDIT 1 section in the question.

Comment: Hey I have checked the EDIT 1 Section. I suggest to you that Go thought the link: http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-fix-file-and-folder-permissions-error-in-wordpress/

Comment: Tried this. But still I see the same error on my admin dashboard.

Comment: what's the error display currently??

Comment: Check the screenshot in the EDIT 1. That is what I get